# Update error while trying to install Spotify

Tags: updates

I'm trying to install the Spotify client on Ubuntu, and I'm fairly new to Linux, so I can't figure out how to resolve this error message that I keep getting:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages Something wicked happened resolving 'repository.spotify.com:http' (- 5 - No address associated with hostname)
```

This error message comes up 3 times (each with a slightly different opening URL) every time I try to run `sudo apt-get update`. I've looked around the internet for answers, I've changed my DNS, but I can't get past this error message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Spelling mistake. :)

`http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stabel/`

should be:

`http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/`

You can actually test this in your very own web browser afterwards.

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake in the post, I didn't copy and paste, the error message doesnt have that mistake.  My bad

Comment: My debugging advice still stands: test the URLs in your browser.

Comment: Okay, I did, and they aren't showing up.  These are the three URLs attached to the error:

http://repsitory.spotify.com/dists/stable/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages

http://repsitory.spotify.com/dists/stable/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US

http://repsitory.spotify.com/dists/stable/non-free/i18n/Translation-en

Firefox tells me it can't find the server at repository.spotify.com, but I can access it directly

Comment: `traceroute repository.spotify.com`

Comment: That returns the following:

traceroute to repository.spotify.com (78.31.8.20), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.200.121.7 (10.200.121.7)  18.193 ms  18.241 ms  33.341 ms
 2  * 165.91.10.1 (165.91.10.1)  30.417 ms  33.339 ms
 3  10.3.4.49 (10.3.4.49)  33.841 ms  33.837 ms  34.529 ms
 4  net-165-91-128-9.net.tamu.edu (165.91.128.9)  35.970 ms  41.058 ms  41.585 ms
 5  farewell-tamu.net.tamu.edu (165.91.128.3)  38.921 ms  38.980 ms  39.636 ms
 6  hstn-lvl3-core-ge-5-0-0-2015.tx-bb.net (192.12.10.117)  42.069 ms  17.621 ms  5.093 ms

Comment: 7  aust-utnoc-core-ge-0-0-0-762.tx-bb.net (192.124.227.205)  9.570 ms  9.995 ms  10.745 ms
 8  67-132.154-153.qwest.net (67.132.154.153)  16.614 ms  17.766 ms  17.780 ms
 9  dap-brdr-04.inet.qwest.net (67.14.2.170)  32.792 ms  32.194 ms  24.175 ms
10  te8-4-10G.ar3.DAL2.gblx.net (64.208.110.201)  15.446 ms  16.446 ms  15.895 ms
11  xe-1-1-2.core-1.centro.hml.uk.as29017.net (64.209.97.98)  124.861 ms  126.345 ms  134.251 ms
12  83-223-121-13.as29017.net (83.223.121.13)  129.717 ms  126.582 ms  125.579 ms
13  78.31.8.20 (78.31.8.20)  124.871 ms  123.713 ms  124.571 ms